# Can i use Java Feign client to request for another API?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign, feign

I have microservice why do some calculations. And there is public api where i can get some data. Can i use Feign to do request to this API?

Comment: Yes, you can. https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do that :

Step 1: create feign client

```
@FeignClient(name="DemoClient", url="url of the api")
public interface DemoClient {
    @GetMapping(value="/get-demo",consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    List<Model> getData();
}
```

Step 2 : Create Model

```
class Model {

}
```

Step 3 : Create Service Layer

```
class DemoService {

   @Autowired
   DemoClient demoClient;

   public void getData() {
       List<Model> objData = this.democlient.getData();
   }

}
```

Hope this will help